# using python to return linked values

Tags: python, pandas, database

Sorry for a stupid question.  I think I need some basics refreshed to answer a problem I'm trying to solve.

Say I'm reading a list in excel like

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| a | team a |
| b | team a |
| c | team b |
| d | team b |

If I wanted to look up each x values' y companion using pandas in python, how would I go about this?  I'm a little unfamiliar with the process of linking data.

For example looking up c would return team b.

EDIT
I'm basically trying to figure out, if y column == team a, then print all of the x values corresponding to team a.

```
for i in teams:

    if Table.loc[(Table['x']==i)]:
    print(Table.loc[(Table['y'])])
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Comment: It's notable that groupby is iterable. `for name, g_df in df.groupby('y'):` where `name` is the name group, `team a`, `team b` and g_df is the corresponding DataFrame with those values.

Answer (score 1):

```py
df.where(df.y=='teama').dropna().x
```